# Custom XML Sort Order?

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have an xml file like

```
<tests>
     <test>
       <categoryname>A</categoryname>
       <region>EU</region>
     </test>

     <test>
       <categoryname>B</categoryname>
       <region>EU</region>
     </test>

     <test>
       <categoryname>C</categoryname>
       <region>USA</region>
     </test>
     <test>
       <categoryname>C</categoryname>
       <region>EU</region>
     </test>
</tests>
```

It is sorted alphabetically and displayed like:

```
A
B
C
```

But I would like to see it with my custom sorting like:

```
C
A
B
```

I have seen similar questions and applied the given answers(xsl codes) for me but unfortunately didn't help, I would be glad if you can help me!
I can add extra attributes/tags/values etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="test">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before('|C|A|B|', 
                                                         concat('|', categoryname, '|')
                                                        ))"
                  data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample input, the result is:

```
<tests>
  <test>
    <categoryname>C</categoryname>
    <region>USA</region>
  </test>
  <test>
    <categoryname>C</categoryname>
    <region>EU</region>
  </test>
  <test>
    <categoryname>A</categoryname>
    <region>EU</region>
  </test>
  <test>
    <categoryname>B</categoryname>
    <region>EU</region>
  </test>
</tests>
```

Comment: I tried your solution on http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_sort and it works but not on mine because my file is being fed to another big report file which is designed in BIRT with lots of features and 650 lines of code :( nevertheless thank you!

Comment: Well, can you show us the portion of your XSLT that would be carrying out the sorting? It should be possible to modify that to use the above approach.

Comment: There isnt any other XSLT, the only one I added is yours, I tried adding it to the big xml file but wasnt accepted, obviously I need a lot of more practice with xml...

The first 3 lines: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.21" id="1">
    <property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 2.6.0.v20100531 Build &lt;2.6.0.v20100609-1613></property>`

Comment: From that short snippet I can see that it is using a namespace, which is an important factor, but I don't think that's enough of it in order for me to help you. In your question text above, can you provide enough of the source XML to indicate where the items to be sorted are relative to the containing document, and what values should be used for the sorting?

Comment: Could this help?This is how the big xml file connects to the one I made and presented above ; `<data-sources>
        <oda-data-source extensionID="org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml" name="Tests DS" id="5">
            <property name="FILELIST">tests.xml</property>
        </oda-data-source>
    </data-sources>` 

What shall I added to this tests.xml so the categorynames would be displayed as in the order I like?

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to provide an XML sample reflective of what you want to sort. And I don't see any category names in the XML you have provided in these comments so far.